# How to show when a subspace is dense in $l^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let's call $Z$ the linear subspace of sequences which converge to $0$ (i.e. after $n>N$) in

$p\in [1,\infty]$ for $l^p$. When would it be a dense subspace of $l^p$?

I barely know the definition of 'dense' but how would one isolate the subspace? Can the thought process be explained? Thanks!

Comment: To show that $Z$ is dense you need the following: Given $x\in l^p$ and $\epsilon > 0 $ there is a $x'\in Z$ with $\Vert x - x' \Vert_p < \epsilon$. How to find such an $x'$? Well it needs to converge to $0$ and should be close to $x$, so how about chopping $x$ off at some point (i.e. replacing $x_k$ by $0$ for high $k$)? Try this for different values of $p$ and check whether it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact even the subset $c_{00}:=\{\ x \in \ell^p \mid \exists\, N_x \ \forall \, i \geq N_x \, \colon x_i=0\ \} \subseteq Z \subseteq \ell^p$ is dense in $\ell^p$ for $p \in [1,\infty)$ and therefore $Z$. To see this consider, for a given $x \in \ell^p$, the sequence $(\hat{x}_n)_n$ with $\hat{x}_i = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_i,  0, 0,\dots)$ and show that it converges in $\ell^p$. (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2652759/400070))

In case of $p=\infty$ try approximating $(1,1,1,\dots)$ with elements of $Z$. (This can't be done, since Z is not dense in $\ell^\infty$.) (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2707983/400070))